# Custom Log4Net appender not creating table or storing entries correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, azure, log4net

I am currently in the process of creating a prototype of a custom Log4Net appender, which is going to store information on all exceptions that occur within the project in an Azure table. The table is to be created based on the model defined in the 'LogEntry' class. Since this is a prototype web application, at the moment I have created a button that throws an exception to start the logger and I have been following this as a guide:

http://www.kongsli.net/nblog/2011/08/15/log4net-writing-log-entries-to-azure-table-storage/

However, when the exception is thrown and the logger is instantiated, the table is not created correctly. Instead of creating the table based on my LogEntry class, it is only generating (what I assume to be the TableServiceContext defaults) of 'PartitionKey', 'RowKey' and 'TimeStamp'. As a result, the logger is failing an no entries are being created in the table.

Below are some extracts from my project:

LogEntry.cs

```
public class LogEntry : TableServiceEntity
{
    public LogEntry()
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // PartitionKey is the current year and month whild RowKey is a combination of the date, time and a GUID.
        // This is so that we are able to query our log entries more efficiently.
        PartitionKey    = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM}", now);
        RowKey          = string.Format("{0:dd HH:mm:ss.fff}-{1}", now, Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    // This region of the class class represents each entry in our log table.
    #region Table Columns
    ...all columns defined here...
    #endregion
}
```

LogServiceContext.cs

```
internal class LogServiceContext : TableServiceContext
{
    public LogServiceContext(string baseAddress, StorageCredentials credentials)
        : base(baseAddress, credentials)
    {
    }

    internal void Log(LogEntry logEntry)
    {
        AddObject("LogEntries", logEntry);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public IQueryable<LogEntry> LogEntries
    {
        get
        {
            return CreateQuery<LogEntry>("LogEntries");
        }
    }
}
```

And an extract from the appender class itself:

```
// Create a new LogEntry and store all necessary details.
// All writing to log is done asynchronically to prevent the write slowing down request handling.
Action doWriteToLog = () => {
    try
    {
        _ctx.Log(new LogEntry
        {
            CreatedDateTime         = DateTime.Now,
            UserName                = loggingEvent.UserName,
            IPAddress               = userIPAddress,
            Culture                 = userCulture,
            OperatingSystem         = userOperatingSystem,
            BrowserVersion          = userCulture,
            ExceptionLevel          = loggingEvent.Level,
            ExceptionDateTime       = loggingEvent.TimeStamp,
            ExceptionMessage        = loggingEvent.RenderedMessage,
            ExceptionStacktrace     = Environment.StackTrace,
            AdditionalInformation   = loggingEvent.RenderedMessage
        });
    }
    catch (DataServiceRequestException e)
    {
        ErrorHandler.Error(string.Format("{0}: Could not wring log entry to {1}: {2}",
            GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName, _tableEndpoint, e.Message));
    }
};
doWriteToLog.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

I am happy to provide any additional information and can package the solution should anyone wish to see the classes in their full form. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

after writing the blog post that you refer to, I have made some small changes to the code.You can see the change in my github repo: https://github.com/vidarkongsli/azuretablestorageappender

Essensially, what I did was replacing SaveChanges() with BeginSaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch, null, null) and removing the BeginInvoke statement from AzureTableStorageAppender.Append(LoggingEvent)

I think this might help the situation.